# Telling LESS CSS how to behave with .active li

Tags: css, html-lists, less

I'm trying to make a menu which has 6 buttons and each of them has its own background color and hover background color. Now, I don't want the background color to show when hover if the link's parent li has an .active class. This is what I tried to do:

```
//I'm making li and li.active links to have the same normal and hover state bg color and then...
li, li.active{
    &:first-child{
        a, a:hover{
            background: @1-n;
        }
        + li{
            a, a:hover{
                background: @2-n;
            }
            + li{
                a, a:hover{
                    background: @3-n;
                }
                + li{
                    a, a:hover{
                        background: @4-n;
                    }
                    + li{
                        a, a:hover{
                            background: @5-n;
                        }
                        + li{
                            a, a:hover{
                                background: @6-n;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//..trying to overwrite the hovers only for normal li so I can't avoid applying them to li.active's ones
li{
    &:first-child{
        a:hover{
            background: @1-h;
        }
        + li{
            a:hover{
                background: @2-h;
            }
            + li{
                a:hover{
                    background: @3-h;
                }
                + li{
                    a:hover{
                        background: @4-h;
                    }
                    + li{
                        a:hover{
                            background: @5-h;
                        }
                        + li{
                            a:hover{
                                background: @6-h;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the CSS that is being generated:

```
li:first-child a, li.active:first-child a, li:first-child a:hover, li.active:first-child a:hover {
    background: @1-n;
}
li:first-child + li a, li.active:first-child + li a, li:first-child + li a:hover, li.active:first-child + li a:hover {
    background: @2-n;
}
li:first-child + li + li a, li.active:first-child + li + li a, li:first-child + li + li a:hover, li.active:first-child + li + li a:hover {
    background: @3-n;
}
li:first-child + li + li + li a, li.active:first-child + li + li + li a, li:first-child + li + li + li a:hover, li.active:first-child + li + li + li a:hover {
    background: @4-n;
}
li:first-child + li + li + li + li a, li.active:first-child + li + li + li + li a, li:first-child + li + li + li + li a:hover, li.active:first-child + li + li + li + li a:hover {
    background: @5-n;
}
li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a, li.active:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a, li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a:hover, li.active:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a:hover {
    background: @6-n;
}
li:first-child a:hover {
    background: @1-h;
}
li:first-child + li a:hover {
    background: @2-h;
}
li:first-child + li + li a:hover {
    background: @3-h;
}
li:first-child + li + li + li a:hover {
    background: @4-h;
}
li:first-child + li + li + li + li a:hover {
    background: @5-h;
}
li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a:hover {
    background: @6-h;
}
```

I apologize if I messed up with my english, I hope I made myself clear!

Thanks!!!!

Comment: `:not()`, although that's not LESS-specific, nor does it work everywhere (IE9+). Or you could just split it out into two statements.

Comment: have you tried using `jquery` for `active` state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer for Many Levels

This utilizes a variation of **option 2** below in my original answer, which means LESS 1.3.1+ needs to be the version used. This actually ends up more readable in this case (in my opinion) because of the use of the variables. I've used just numbers (`1`) and then a number with "h" (`1h`) to represent the base background and the desired hover state background respectively.

**LESS**

```
ul {
    li {
        @first: ~':first-child';
        @withActive: ~'.active';
        @noHover: ~'a';
        @withHover: ~'a:hover';
        @level2: ~'+ li';
        @level3: ~'+ li + li'; 
        @level4: ~'+ li + li + li'; 
        @level5: ~'+ li + li + li + li';
        @level6: ~'+ li + li + li + li + li';    
        &@{first}, 
        &@{withActive}@{first} {
           @{noHover}, @{withHover} {
             background: 1;
           }
        }      
        &@{first} { 
            @{level2}, 
            @{level2}@{withActive} {
              @{noHover}, @{withHover} {
                background: 2;
              }
            }
            @{level3}, 
            @{level3}@{withActive} {
              @{noHover}, @{withHover} {
                background: 3;
              }
            }
            @{level4}, 
            @{level4}@{withActive} {
              @{noHover}, @{withHover} {
                background: 4;
              }
            }
            @{level5}, 
            @{level5}@{withActive} {
              @{noHover}, @{withHover} {
                 background: 5;
              }
            }
            @{level6}, 
            @{level6}@{withActive} {
              @{noHover}, @{withHover} {
                 background: 6;
              }
            }      
            @{withHover} { background: 1h;}
            @{level2} @{withHover} { background: 2h;}
            @{level3} @{withHover} { background: 3h;}
            @{level4} @{withHover} { background: 4h;}
            @{level5} @{withHover} { background: 5h;}
            @{level6} @{withHover} { background: 6h;}
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
ul li:first-child a,
ul li.active:first-child a,
ul li:first-child a:hover, /* <-- Over written */
ul li.active:first-child a:hover {
  background: 1;
}
ul li:first-child + li a,
ul li:first-child + li.active a,
ul li:first-child + li a:hover, /* <-- Over written */
ul li:first-child + li.active a:hover {
  background: 2;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li a,
ul li:first-child + li + li.active a,
ul li:first-child + li + li a:hover, /* <-- Over written */
ul li:first-child + li + li.active a:hover {
  background: 3;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li + li a,
ul li:first-child + li + li + li.active a,
ul li:first-child + li + li + li a:hover, /* <-- Over written */
ul li:first-child + li + li + li.active a:hover {
  background: 4;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li a,
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li.active a,
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li a:hover, /* <-- Over written */
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li.active a:hover {
  background: 5;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a,
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li.active a,
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a:hover, /* <-- Over written */
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li.active a:hover {
  background: 6;
}

/* These over write the third lines of the above output due to the css cascade */
ul li:first-child a:hover {
  background: 1h;
}
ul li:first-child + li a:hover {
  background: 2h;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li a:hover {
  background: 3h;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li + li a:hover {
  background: 4h;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li a:hover {
  background: 5h;
}
ul li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li a:hover {
  background: 6h;
}
```

### Original Answer Before Mentioning All the Levels

I've cut the code below to just the issue you relate. This can be adapted for the `+ li` code.

**Option 1 (very readable)**

This (1) keeps the color definition in one place, and (2) groups the two via the comma, but (3) it repeats much selector code, though (4) it is very readable:

```
ul{
    li{
        &:first-child a, 
        &.active:first-child a:hover {
          background: red;         
        }
        &:first-child a:hover {
          background: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2 (code selector once)**

This has advantages (1) and (2) from option 1, and overcomes issue (3) by utilizing dynamic selector building with variables (needs LESS 1.3.1+) to make the selector code only input once, however, it could be a little less obvious what is going to produce, and so loses advantage (4) from option 1.

```
ul {
    li {
        @noActive: ~':first-child a';
        @withActive: ~'.active@{noActive}';
        &@{noActive}, 
        &@{withActive}:hover {
             background: red;
        }
        &@{noActive}{ 
           &:hover { background: blue;}
        }
   }
}
```

**CSS Output for Both**

```
ul li:first-child a,
ul li.active:first-child a:hover {
  background: red;
}
ul li:first-child a:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, great idea and very simple to follow, thank you very much Scott!

Answer (score 1):

In order to use pseudo-classes (:hover, etc) in less, you have to use the & operator, also you have the order of some of your pseudo-classes mixed up. If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, it should be something like this:

```
ul {
  li,
  li.active {
    &:first-child {
      a {
        background: red;

        &:hover {
          background: blue;
        }
      }

      +li {
        a {
          background: green;

          &:hover {
            background: yellow;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps; if it doesn't work, post the CSS that was generated from your LESS file in addition to the CSS that you desire as output so we can take a look.

Comment: The problem is that I've got 6 <a> buttons, and each one has its own bg color and bg hover color but the hover color should't display if the button's parent li has an .active class. I edited the main post with the actual code I'm using and the CSS that is being generated. Thanks!